# If $\Omega$ is locally Lipschitz, then $\Omega = \bigcup_{k = 1}^N \Omega_k$ for $\Omega_k$ star shaped with respect to an open ball $B_k$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading Galdi's *Introduction to the mathematical theory of Navier Stokes equations* and there is an argument which comes up quite often that I really don't understand.

In many theorems of Chapter $3$, we prove the existence of solutions of a problem defined on an open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ that statisfies the following condition:
$$\Omega = \bigcup_{k  = 1}^N \Omega_k$$
where each $\Omega_k$ is star shaped with respect to some open ball $B_k$ with $\overline{B}_k \subset \Omega_k$.

Then, in the next chapters, he uses these results but for $\Omega$ bounded and locally Lipschitz. Therefore, it seems to me that a bounded locally Lipschitz open set should satisfy the above condition, but I really have no idea how to show that.. Clearly $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact, so we can cover it by a finite number of balls, but then how do we prove that they are star-shaped with respect to some other balls $B_k$ ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full, rigorous argument for this is tedious and not something one should do in public :) Instead, let me give you an example that hopefully gives the right idea.

Basically it all boils down to choosing your cover in a smart way, ensuring that you can fit a sufficiently tall cylinder centered at the boundary at every point. Why does this help? Well, imagine the graph is given locally in the usual first $n-1$ coordinates, i.e.
$$
\partial\Omega= \{ (x',x_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: x_n=f(x'),\, |x'|<R\},
$$
for a Lipschitz function $f$ with constant $M$ (we may assume $f(0)=0$). Now notice that if we consider the cylinder
$$
\mathcal{C}:=\{ (x',x_n): |x'|<R, |x_n|<30MR\},
$$
then $\mathcal{C}\cap \Omega$ satisfies your starshaped condition. One way to look at this is that the cylinder is "tall" enough to guarantee that the top of it lies well above $f$, actually far enough so that any cone with "aperture" $\cot^{-1} M$ and vertex on $\partial\Omega\cap \mathcal{C}$, contains the whole top of $\mathcal{C}$; and recall that the Lipschitz condition means that all these (open) cones are disjoint from the graph of $f$.

Edit:

Let $X=(0, 30MR)$ be the center of the top of our cylinder $\mathcal{C}$, then we show that the line segments joining $X$ and any point on the boundary are all above the graph of $f$. From the argument you'll see that there's some wiggle room so that the same is true for points in a neighborhood of $X$.

First notice that the set
$$
\Gamma(x'):= \{ (y',y_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\times \mathbb{R}: M|y'-x'|<(y_n-f(x'))\}\subset \mathbb{R}^n,
$$
is the *convex* right cone with aperture $\cot^{-1} M$, with vertex $(x',f(x'))$ and opening upward. I claim that for any $x'\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, we have $\Gamma(x')\cap \text{Graph}(f)=\emptyset$.

The claim is actually a characterization of $f$ being a Lipschitz function with constant $M$ (which we assume defined on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$). Let $(y',y_n)\in \Gamma(x')\cap \text{Graph}(f)$ for some $x'\in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. By definition of the graph, this means $y_n=f(y')$, and by the Lipschitz condition on $f$,
$$
|f(y')-f(x')|\leq M|x'-y'|,
$$
however, since $(y',f(y'))\in \Gamma(x')$,
$$
M|x'-y'|<(f(y')-f(x')),
$$
which is clearly a contradiction, and the claim is proved.

To finish we notice that for any $|x'|<R$ we have $X\in \Gamma(x')$: Since $f(0)=0$, $|f(x')|\leq M|x'|<MR $, so that $(30MR-f(x')) \geq 20MR >M|x'|$ and this is exactly the definition of $X\in \Gamma(x')$.

Comment: Do you have any reference where the whole proof is done ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any off the top of my head where this is worked out in detail.

Comment: Sorry but I am not very comfortable with your explanation: Why $\mathcal C \cap \Omega$ satisfies the starshaped condition ? I have never seen the notion of vertex, is it possible to write the last paragraph with more details ?

Comment: @Falcon: I've added some detail to the star-shaped condition. Hope this helps.